# Facing issues duplicating two autosliding divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using the below script to autoslide two divs.

Below is my code.

**The HTML:**

```
<div id="gallery">
  <div id="slider" style="width: 6000px; left: -500px;">
     <div><aside class="widget widget_testimonial amr_widget" id="attitude_testimonial-3"><h3 class="widget-title">Main Title</h3>
        <div class="testimonial-icon"></div>

        <div class="testimonial-post">Content here.</div>

        <div class="testimonial-author">

            <span>Sub content</span>
        </div>

        </aside></div>
     <div><aside class="widget widget_testimonial amr_widget" id="attitude_testimonial-3"><h3 class="widget-title">Main Title</h3>
        <div class="testimonial-icon"></div>

        <div class="testimonial-post">Content here.</div>

        <div class="testimonial-author">

            <span>Sub content</span>
        </div>

        </aside></div>
     <div><aside class="widget widget_testimonial amr_widget" id="attitude_testimonial-3"><h3 class="widget-title">Main Title</h3>
        <div class="testimonial-icon"></div>

        <div class="testimonial-post">Content here.</div>

        <div class="testimonial-author">

            <span>Sub content</span>
        </div>

        </aside></div>
  </div>
  <span id="prev"></span>
  <span id="next"></span>
</div>


<div id="galleryTwo">
  <div id="sliderTwo" style="width: 6000px; left: -500px;">
     <div><aside class="widget widget_testimonial amr_widget" id="attitude_testimonial-3"><h3 class="widget-title">Main Title</h3>
        <div class="testimonial-icon"></div>

        <div class="testimonial-post">Content here.</div>

        <div class="testimonial-author">

            <span>Sub content</span>
        </div>

        </aside></div>
     <div><aside class="widget widget_testimonial amr_widget" id="attitude_testimonial-3"><h3 class="widget-title">Main Title</h3>
        <div class="testimonial-icon"></div>

        <div class="testimonial-post">Content here.</div>

        <div class="testimonial-author">

            <span>Sub content</span>
        </div>

        </aside></div>
     <div><aside class="widget widget_testimonial amr_widget" id="attitude_testimonial-3"><h3 class="widget-title">Main Title</h3>
        <div class="testimonial-icon"></div>

        <div class="testimonial-post">Content here.</div>

        <div class="testimonial-author">

            <span>Sub content</span>
        </div>

        </aside></div>
  </div>
  <span id="prevTwo"></span>
  <span id="nextTwo"></span>
</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
/* Scolling review starts */
#gallery{
  position:relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:960px;
  height:178px;
}
#slider{
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  height:278px;
}
#slider > div {
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  width:960px;
  height:178px;
}
#slider > div img{
  width:100%;
}
/* buttons */
#gallery > span{
  cursor:pointer;
  position:absolute;
  width:50px;
  height:100%;
  background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  opacity:0.5;
}
#next{
  right:0px;
}
#gallery > span:hover{
  opacity:1;
}
/* Scolling review ends */

/* Scolling review Two starts */
#galleryTwo{
  position:relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:960px;
  height:218px;
}
#sliderTwo{
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  height:278px;
}
#sliderTwo > div {
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  width:960px;
  height:178px;
}
#sliderTwo > div img{
  width:100%;
}
/* buttons */
#galleryTwo > span{
  cursor:pointer;
  position:absolute;
  width:50px;
  height:100%;
  background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  opacity:0.5;
}
#nextTwo{
  right:0px;
}
#galleryTwo > span:hover{
  opacity:1;
}
/* Scolling review Two ends */
```

**The Script:**

```
var $gal = $('#gallery'),
    $sli = $('#slider'),
    $box = $('#slider > div'),
    W    = $gal.width(), // 500
    N    = $box.length,  // 3
    C    = 0,            // a counter
    intv;

$sli.width(W*N);


$('#prev, #next').click(function(){
  C = (this.id=='next' ? ++C : --C) <0 ? N-1 : C%N;
  $sli.stop().animate({left: -C*W },800);  
}); 

function auto(){
  intv = setInterval(function(){
    $('#next').click();
  }, 3000);
}
auto(); // start

$('#gallery').hover(function( e ){
  return e.type=='mouseenter'?clearInterval(intv):auto();
});

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var $galTwo = $('#galleryTwo'),
    $sliTwo = $('#sliderTwo'),
    $boxTwo = $('#sliderTwo > div'),
    WTwo    = $galTwo.width(), // 500
    NTwo    = $boxTwo.length,  // 3
    CTwo    = 0,            // a counter
    intv;

$sliTwo.width(WTwo*NTwo);


$('#prevTwo, #nextTwo').click(function(){
  CTwo = (this.id=='nextTwo' ? ++CTwo : --CTwo) <0 ? NTwo-1 : CTwo%NTwo;
  $sliTwo.stop().animate({left: -CTwo*WTwo },800);  
}); 

function autoTwo(){
  intv = setInterval(function(){
    $('#nextTwo').click();
  }, 3000);
}
autoTwo(); // start

$('#galleryTwo').hover(function( e ){
  return e.type=='mouseenter'?clearInterval(intv):auto();
});
```

**The fiddle link:**

**[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/xdWUp/)**

**The Issue:**

I am creating an autosliding div by using two div ids `#gallery` and `#galleryTwo`. I need same functionality in both, so I have renamed their ids and used them at different places. It works fine, but on the fiddle (as well as on my workflow), when you hover your mouse on the autosliding div, the auto slide for the duplicated div i.e `#galleryTwo` stops which was sliding automatically initially. I am stuck up on this part of the code and need to make both of them auto slide even hover happens or not.

Comment: instead of creating 2 ids, you can use 1 class...

Comment: I tried using class, but it somehow did not work. so I went ahead and decided to create unique div names and replicate them. - @Kiran

Comment: @NathanLee you want [this](http://jsfiddle.net/xdWUp/1/)?

Comment: Yes @TilwinJoy .. Could you throw some light on it ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `intv` is global, which is pointing to the interval set for the second slider. Whenever you hover either of the sliders, As you can see in the code below

```
$('#gallery').hover(function( e ){
 return e.type=='mouseenter'?clearInterval(intv):auto();
});

$('#galleryTwo').hover(function( e ){
 return e.type=='mouseenter'?clearInterval(intv):auto();
});
```

You're clearing `intv` hence the second slider will stop. If you want to control them separately, you need to have to different variables pointing to each sliders intervals.

If you don't want to control the slider on hover, you can remove these hover listeners :)